# Python 3.9: Reading Background Processes

Tags: python

As the title states, I am currently running the Python 3.9 interpreter. The end goal is to terminate any process that is found to be:

a.) Running

b.) In the background (task icon available in the taskbar, yet not open as a window)

c.) Matching the `winName` variable created via an `input()` run at the beginning of the script.

For example, if I passed "Steam" as the `winName`, the program would check if Steam is running (via `win32ui.FindWindow(None, winName)`), then check if the program is in the background (where I am currently stuck), then close the program (via `win32gui.PostMessage(winName, win32con.WM_CLOSE, 0, 0)`).

Currently, I am importing win32ui/gui/con. Optimally, I would like to use these options to read for background processes, but I am not opposed to importing/installing any other modules.

Comment: I can't recognize a question in this. (*"Could someone please write something like this for me?"* is not a question)

Comment: @Tomalak the question is, how to check if a program is running in the background with win32whatever

Comment: I recommend using psutil, which is an excellent cross-platform module that can check all running programs in a system.  You can also use subprocess but I have found psutil to be faster.

Comment: Thank you Josh, I will look into psutil as an option.